# How can make Bootstrap's horizontal form labels smaller with CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap has a lot of [examples for types of forms](https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/#forms). I'm interested in using the "Horizontal form" which looks like this

[image: Picture.png]

This is what it looks like after outlining some elements with the web inspector toolbar:

[image: Picture 2.png]

I am working inside of a popup modal and space is already a bit tight. I tried adding bootstrap's grid system's `.span1` and `.span2` to the labels as a class, but it is not giving the desired behavior.

Is there a way to use some other aspect of bootstrap to get the desired behavior (i.e. tighten up the amount of space that labels on a horizontal form take up)? What is the proper way to do this? I'm using bootstrap version `2.1`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i am not aware if bootstrap has got something defined for it..below is a workaround..

```
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" style="width:auto" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
<div class="controls" style="margin-left:auto">
<input type="text" class="input-small" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
</div>
</div>
```

i added `style="width:auto"` which was default `140px` and `style="margin-left:auto"` which was default `160px`. Also `class="input-small"` to reduce the input field width to squeeze out more space so that it fits in modal..

Now you tweak further to fit it as per your needs..

Comment: seems like it would work - i'm surprised bootstrap doesn't have a better built-in support for this. thanks

Answer (score 5):

To reduce the vertical spacing, `form-control-sm` shrinks the font-size (using Bootstrap 4):

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group form-row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label form-control-sm">Label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input class="form-control form-control-sm">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```